# Containment of two varieties with a lot of intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, intersection-theory

Given a projective variety $X\subset \mathbb P^n$ and a curve $C\subset \mathbb P^n$, when can I conclude that $C\subset X$, from the fact that $C$ and $X$ have 'many' points in common. I.e., is there a number $N$ (depending on numerical invariants of the embeddings of $X$ and $C$) so that if $X\cap C$ contains at least $N$ points, then $C\subset X$?

Comment: Suppose $C$ is irreducible. Bezout's theorem then says that either $C\subset X$ or $X\cap C$ contains at most $(\deg X)(\deg C)$ points.

Comment: @Boris: The OP does not seem to assume that X is a hypersurface.

Comment: There certainly is some such $N$. Let $X = H_1 \cap \cdots \cap H_r$ for hypersurfaces $H_i$. Bukh's argument shows that, if $\# (X \cap C) > \max_i (\deg H_i)(\deg C)$, then $C$ is contained in all the $H_i$, so $C \subset \bigcap H_i = X$. I don't know whether that is the best bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the variety $X$ and the curve $C$ have degree $a,b$ respectively. Take $N = ab$.
Now, if you know that $X$ and $C$ intersect in $k$ points counted with multiplicity with $k >N$ then, by Bézout theorem you get $C\subseteq X$.

For instance, assume $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ is variety of degree three with two singular points of multiplicity two. Then the line $L$ joining the two points intersects $X$ at least in four points counted with multiplicity. Then, $L\subset X$.